# Add value from Array to an XY Series

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-sqlite

I want to add a value from SQLite to an XY series to create a diagram. Here is what I've done so far:

```
 Double a, b;
 mDbHelper = new NotesDbAdapter(this);
 mDbHelper.open();

 Cursor notesCursor = mDbHelper.fetchAllNotes();
 startManagingCursor(notesCursor);
 ArrayList x = new ArrayList();
 ArrayList y = new ArrayList();
 notesCursor.moveToFirst();

 for(int i = 0; i<notesCursor.getCount();i++){
     a = notesCursor.getDouble(notesCursor.getColumnIndex(mDbHelper.KEY_ROWID));
     b = notesCursor.getDouble(notesCursor.getColumnIndex(mDbHelper.KEY_RESULT));
 }
 x.add(a);
 y.add(b);

 notesCursor.moveToNext();

 mCurrentSeries.add(x, y);
 if (mChartView != null) {
      mChartView.repaint();
 }
```

But I've got a problem at the line:

> `mCurrentSeries.add(x, y);`

How I can add an Array to an XY series? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

not sure what library you are using here to create your diagram (chart?). I use aChartEngine which is pretty good. The code I use to get a dataset containing a time series  in aChartEngine is:

```
public static XYMultipleSeriesDataset getDemoDataset(Cursor c,
            String title, String... columnName) {
        XYMultipleSeriesDataset dataset = new XYMultipleSeriesDataset();

        TimeSeries series = new TimeSeries(title);


        try {
            if (c.moveToFirst()) {
                do {
                    int mins = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(columnName[0]));


                    java.util.Date date =null;
                    try{
                        date = DateFactory.stringToDate(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(columnName[1])));
                    }catch(Exception e){

                    }
                    if(date==null){
                        continue;
                    }
                    series.add(date, mins);
                } while (c.moveToNext());
            } else {
                Log.d(TAG, "There were no values in the cursor.");
            }
        } finally {
            Log.d(TAG, "finally from getDemoDataset being called");
            c.close();
        }

        dataset.addSeries(series);

        return dataset;
    }
```

Comment: yes, i want to make a chart, and i want to get the value (x, y) from my database (sqlite) which contain many x and y value that i inserted before, do you know how to do that? thanks before

Comment: Hi, did you read my answer? It takes 2 values from a database and uses them for the points on the chart.

Comment: yes, ive read ur answer but it didn't work, do you mind to send me the example project? thanks before